# How can I change the font color using axlsx for a cell containing a number?

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

Here is a test script to create a simple workbook using the `axlsx` gem. I am trying to loop over the rows and cells and change the font colors to red. However, only the cells that contain text (i.e. the first two rows in this example) are changing to red. The rows containing numbers are remaining the default black color. Any idea how to change the color of cells which contain numbers?

```
require 'axlsx'

Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
 p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "test") do |sheet|
        sheet.add_row ["First", "Second", "Third"]
        sheet.add_row ["First", "Second", "Third"]
        sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
        sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
        sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
        sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
        sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]

        sheet.rows.each do |x|
            x.cells.each do |i| 
                i.color = "E8000"
            end
        end

  end
p.serialize('test.xlsx')
end
```